# Get time difference in minutes between current time and the time that data was inserted to DB

Tags: oracle

I have a system making third party API request to another server. But i want to make sure the user doesn't request again within the next 15 minutes of the first request. So I check time difference in below method which is not working correctly,

```
ROUND(sysdate - d.CREATE_DATE,2) as PASSED_TIME
```

Here `d.CREATE_DATE` is also saved by using `SYSDATE` keyword when the first request is sent. I get a number out put but it doesn't seem to be right. 
So I want to know how can i take time difference in minutes

Comment: MySQL does not support `SYSDATE` AFAIK.  What is your actual database?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it supports. Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sysdate

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sorry. Oracle database

Comment: You need to use `SYSTIMESTAMP` and also record the incoming timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For oracle, it is enough to just subtract the dates if the field "CREATE_DATE" is "date" datatype and multiply by 24*60 to get the difference in minutes.
Eg:

```
select to_char(sysdate-15/24/60,'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as first_request /*15 minutes back*/
      ,to_char(sysdate,'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as current_request
      ,(sysdate  - sysdate +15/24/60)*24*60 as diff_in_minutes
 from dual
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be recording and comparing to `SYSTIMESTAMP`:

```
SELECT
    EXTRACT (day FROM ts) * 24*60 +
    EXTRACT (hour FROM ts) * 60 +
    EXTRACT (minute FROM ts) AS PASSED_TIME
FROM
(
    SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP - CREATE_TS ts
    FROM yourTable
) t;
```

This answer assumes that the `CREATE_TS` column stores the incoming timestamps, using `SYSTIMESTAMP` as the incoming value.

Comment: `SYSDATE` does have a time component, you just can't directly access the time elements of a date with `extract()`. (I'm 100% sure you know that really, of course *8-)

Comment: @AlexPoole Oracle is to me like a complex maze of APIs.  It is also one of the most powerful databases out there.